# Swift Dictionary array

Tags: swift, dictionary

I am using Swift 1.2 and trying to get the correct syntax for this declaration that comes from a previous version of Swift:

```
 var dataSource: Dictionary<String, String> [][] = [[],[]]
```

The error I get is :

> Array types are now written with the brackets around the element type.

I just don't know how to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax has changed since then. As your error reads:

> Array types are now written with the brackets around the element type.

So instead of `Dictionary<String, String>[][]` you wrap the brackets around the type for example `[[Dictionary<String, String>]]` or using shorthand syntax: `[[[String: String]]]`:

```
var dataSource: [[[String: String]]] = [[],[]]
```